# Backbone.js - How to get an array of object literals out of a collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm trying to keep an array of object literals in sync with server data.  These objects are being placed on a Google map via backbone.googlemaps extension.

I have a collection:

`var LocationList = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: Location, url: '/locations' })`

How can I grab an array of object literals from this `LocationList` collection?  My goal is such:

`[{name: "Home", address: "123 Pleasant St"}, {name: "Work", address: "123 Unpleasant St"}]`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are looking for the `.toJSON()` method of the collection, [see here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON):

```
var locations = new LocationList();

locations.toJSON();
```

Answer (score 3):

use underscore.js pluck method: http://underscorejs.org/#pluck